# ng-repeat is not showing all values of the array when i select a particular option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

i am working with `ui-select-match` and `ng-repeat`

i have an array with five values as shown below in `occurrence`.
My code is working fine except that when i select `first` option `all` disappears from the dropdown and after that if when i  select "second"
than "all" shows up in dropdown options.
here is my html code

```html
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" id="sdlPrdAddS_sdlAvlF_awkC">
        <div class="formElement" id="sdlPrdAddS_sdlAvlF_awk">
            <p id="sdlPrdAddS_sdlAvlF_awkL">
                <label>{{'healthcareService.addSchedule.availability.occurrence' | translate}}</label><span class="red">*</span></p>
            <ui-select multiple name="occurrenceInMonth" data-ng-model="scheduleFormObj.daysOfWeekInput.occurrence" id="sS_adR_occureence" on-select="removeExtraFields()" ui-select-required="true">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="{{'healthcareService.addSchedule.scheduleDetails.select' | translate}}">
                    {{$item}}
                </ui-select-match>{{occurrence}}
                <ui-select-choices repeat="occurrence in scheduleStaticObjs.occurrence">
                    <div ng-bind-html="occurrence"></div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
   </div>
```

My object is this:

```
scheduleStaticObjs.occurrence =
["All","First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth"]
```

Comment: Please edit the question, it is unreadable like this. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to check what happens in your on-select="removeExtraField()" as it might be the problem

Check out [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohelal/w93m5r4u/36/) to see a working version of what you might need

```
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="test" theme="bootstrap">
      <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Pick one...">
        {{$item}}
      </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="val in test_values">
        <span ng-bind="val"></span>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS below:

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.select']);

angular
  .module('test')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test_values = ["All", "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"]
  });
```

Hope this helps